# Como pedir opinião sobre alguma ferramenta?

Tags: debate

Fiz a seguinte pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/172728/qual-a-melhor-ferramenta-para-relat%C3%B3rio-no-visual-studio-2015?noredirect=1#comment355940_172728 e a mesma foi marcada como pendente por ser voltada para opiniões de usuários.

Porém o que eu quero é justamente as opiniões deles.

Como devo perguntar?

Comment: "Melhor" é subjetivo ao contexto e a aplicação, perguntas baseadas em opinão estão fora do escopo do site mas existe uma lugar para elas que é o [chat] ver sala estouro de pilha.

Comment: Ver também: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/488/gorilla-vs-shark

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"Melhor" é subjetivo ao contexto e a aplicação, perguntas baseadas em opiniões estão fora do escopo do site, entretanto existe um lugar para elas que é o [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=pt.stackoverflow.com) (ver sala estouro de pilha) onde os assuntos são mais livres além de trocar ideias com um pessoal bacana.

Quando estiver nessa situação tente trocar o texto ou as palavras subjetivas como "melhor" ou "qualidade", que carregam um forte sentido de algo bom ou correto, por uma lista de características objetivas. Como diz aquele ditado "o que é bom para você pode não ser para mim".

Answer (score 11):

O problema com tentar encontrar algo "melhor" que o resto é que cada pessoa dando uma resposta pode ter necessidades, habilidades e conceitos de uso diferentes para a mesma ferramenta. Por isso que, mesmo depois de 40 anos, o mundo da computação não consegue se decidir se o "melhor" editor é [vi](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi) ou [Emacs](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Emacs).
<sup>Dica: Certamente é vi</sup>

Então cada resposta vai ser dada no que o *autor* considera como fatores pra considerar sua sugestão a melhor (velocidade e rodar em linux, por exemplo), e esses podem não ser os mesmos que *você* avaliaria para considerar que algo é o melhor (e.g. exportar pra PDF e suporte a paralelismo). O resultado dessa confluência de objetivos e óticas diferentes é que a maioria das respostas não vai ser tão útil assim pra você (porque estão avaliando a ferramenta sob critérios diferentes dos seus), e a maioria dos votos é dado de forma menos objetiva que o normal (já que é os votantes vão votar na resposta que avalia a ferramenta sob os mesmos critérios que eles). Então as respostas se tornam um "concurso de popularidade".

A sugestão mais comum, mais usada, acaba recebendo mais votos. Mesmo que não seja a mais apropriada pra resolver o *seu* problema.

Por isso o caminho mais comum é de o de tratar essas recomendações como qualquer outro problema que resolvemos aqui no site: bem definido e objetivo. Ao invés de perguntar o "melhor" algo, perguntar qual a opção que atende aos seus requerimentos, que tenha as funções que você precisa, ou que te deixe usar da maneira que você espera. Existem 2 benefícios nisso:

1. **O mesmo efeito de "patinho de borracha" do SO se aplica**: Ter que explicar um problema para outras pessoas, de maneira clara, te força a pensar sobre ele um pouco mais a fundo, ou de maneira diferente. E você pode acabar entendendo muito melhor o que você está procurando, mesmo antes de perguntar.
2. **Até pessoas que tem preferências diferentes são capazes de avaliar o problema sob as *suas* necessidades**: Uma descrição objetiva do que você procura permite que qualquer um que tenha familiaridade com as soluções possa te recomendar algo que atenda mesmo que, pessoalmente, faça uso de outra ferramenta. Eu posso até preferir vim (obviamente), mas se você me disser que tem 23 dedos nas mãos e gosta que seu editor de texto seja um sistema operacional... vou te recomendar emacs.

Essas sugestões parecem excesso de preciosismo, mas permitem que você consiga respostas muito mais aplicáveis ao seu problema e também permitem que as próximas centenas, ou milhares de pessoas, que visitarem sua pergunta ao longo dos anos saibam *exatamente* o que você queria, e se as respostas fazem sentido ou não.